# Function and inputs python

Tags: python

I'm having issues with getting the program to spit out the correct output.
The input is for expample:
Enter year:2
Enter months:6
Enter the days:73
[ this would be the output needed (below) ]
"Total time in years is 2.7 years"

```
y = input("Enter value for year: ")
m = input("Enter value for month: ")
d = input("Enter value for day: ")
def gettime(y, m, d):
    totaltime = y + m / 12 + d / 365
    return totaltime
print ("The total time in years is: " + gettime())
```

How can I fix the output to spit out the correct calculation. I'm trying to gather the user input and output the calculations taking place in the function.

Comment: your month, year and day are strings. convert them to integer first and then back.

Comment: Also, you should pass in those variables into your `gettime()` function since it currently takes 3 arguments and you've passed in 0. Something like `gettime(int(y), int(m), int(d))` should work.

Comment: @rchome                                                                                                                 
 File "/Users/error404/Desktop/python work/simpleInterest.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ("The total time in years is: " +gettime(int(y), int(m), int(d)))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str                                                    that is the error i got ^

Comment: @NecronTombWorld the error message is quite clear. You're concatenating a string and a float. You should cast the result of `gettime()` to a `str`.

Comment: @NecronTombWorld, check my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
def gettime(y: int, m: int, d: int) -> float:
    totaltime = y + m / 12 + d / 365
    return totaltime

print ("The total time in years is: " + str(gettime(y, m, d)))
```

You have to use the built-in function [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), in order to convert the `float` value returned by `gettime()` to a string and then to concatenate it with an other string with the `+` operator.